# Javascript - Sticky button depending on the width header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a sticky header with an `ul` and one `div`.

The sticky header work fine, but i want to make sticky the `div` too, only when the screen width are `>= 981px`.

---

### Code

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sub-header-info">
    <div class="wrap-perfil">
        <nav class="barra-header">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="actividad" href="index.php">Actividad</a></li>
                <li><a class="favoritos" href="#">Favoritos</a></li>
                <li><a class="seguidores" href="seguidores.php">Seguidores</a></li>
                <li><a class="seguidos" href="seguidos.php">Siguiendo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-perfil">
    <div class="boton-seguir"><a href="#">Seguir</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boton-seguir {
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
.boton-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 161;
    right: 90px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var stickyOffset = $('#sub-header-info').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('#sub-header-info'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});

var stickyOffset2 = $('.boton-seguir').offset().top;
    var boton = $('.boton-seguir');
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (screen.width >= 981 && scroll >= stickyOffset2)
        boton.addClass('boton-fixed')
```

---

**What I spected:**

[image]

Here is a **<kbd>[Live Demo](http://codecoffee.co/usuario/perfil/index.php)</kbd>** .

What is wrong here? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I use mediaqueries, but how I make the sticky button on scroll only for `>= 981` px? in lower resolutions this `div` have another position...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, because your button is not inside of the sticky div, you're going to have to make it sticky as well.  Modify your JavaScript like this:

```
var stickyOffset = $('#sub-header-info').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('#sub-header-info'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      stickyBtn = sticky.next();

  if (scroll >= stickyOffset) {
    sticky.addClass('fixed');
    stickyBtn.addClass('fixedBtn');
  }
  else {
    sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    stickyBtn.removeClass('fixedBtn');
  }
});
```

Now you can catch that button with media queries like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
  .wrap-perfil.fixedBtn {
    position:fixed;
    /* We need a z-index greater than #sub-header-info's */
    z-index: 1000000;
    /* Probably better to remove the negative-top off of the child element, 
     * but this hack will demonstrate how it works.  :) */
    top: 60px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .wrap-perfil.fixedBtn {
    /* Add CSS for smaller screens here. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Great.  Let me know how it goes, and make sure you use the latest version: I initially forgot my curly braces around the media query, and forgot the `position:fixed;` in the  CSS.

Comment: You miss to add `var stickyOffset = $('#sub-header-info').offset().top;`  in your javascript code. Adding this, work correctly. Thanks @Jonathan !

Comment: Thanks.  I added the line into the answer.  :)